# Show correct Bubble in Android Studio when nothing has been deployed

Tags: android-studio, deployment

I repeatedly run into the problem, that Android Studio is not deploying the app on the mobile device.

When I hit the play button it shows the following message in the 'Run'-Tab:

```
02/16 12:08:06: Launching 'App' on Physical Device.
Unable to determine application id: com.android.tools.idea.run.ApkProvisionException: No outputs for the main artifact of variant: debug
```

Normally, I can fix this by hitting the "Sync project with gradle files"-Button or just trying to deploy again. So this is not the main problem.

The annoying part is, that Android Studio shows the green "Success. Operation succeeded"-Bubble next to the run tab, even if nothing was deployed to the device.

Is this a problem in the IDE? Can it somehow be configured to show an error instead?

I am using Android Studio 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

run -> edit configuration -> before launch

click on add button and select **gradle-aware make**
then press apply and then OK

by above step my app run successful